# How to compare datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have to show the date `2018/01/30` if the datetime is between `2018/01/30 04:59:59.000` and `2018/01/31 04:59:59.000`

I have a table called **DataEntry**. I want to move those records by date as per my criteria.

This DataEntry table have TransferTime that datatype is datetime.

As per my criteria if the TransferTime is `2018/01/30 01:30:59.000` then the date should be `2018/01/29`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply just write like this:

```
select 
 case when DATEPART(HOUR,'2018/01/30 01:30:59.000') >= 05 then cast('2018/01/30 01:30:59.000' as date) 
      else cast(dateadd(Dd,-1,'2018/01/30 01:30:59.000' )as date) 
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a guess on vague logic, but perhaps using `CONVERT` and `DATEADD`?

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(3),DT) AS DT
    FROM (VALUES('20180130 04:59:59.000'),('20180131 01:00:34.000'),('20180130 01:30:59.000')) V(DT))
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(SECOND, -17999,DT)) AS D, DT
FROM VTE;
```

It's worth noting that you, oddly, state that `'20180130 04:59:59.000'` **AND** `''20180131 04:59:59.000'` should both be on the same day, (`'20180130'`). This doesn't make any sense, as Days don't overlap like that. Thus the latter time would show `'20180131'`, as it's exactly 24 hours later.

If the former time should actually be `'20180129'`, then change `-17999` to `-18000`, or `SECOND,-17999` to `HOUR, -5`.

Answer (score 1):

this will do too:

```
select cast(dateadd(second, -17999,Transfertime) as date)
```

being 17999 = 4hs59m59s in seconds